# ДозироваННо или дозироваНо?

Tags: орфография, причастия, наречия, нн

*Нужно пользоваться компьютером дозирова**нн**о.*
Верно с двумя -Н- в слове «дозированно»? Наречие ведь здесь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Нужно пользоваться компьютером  (как?) **дозированно**.*

**В наречии** пишутся две буквы НН, причем это определяется сразу, "тонкого анализа" не требуется.

**Пояснение**

1. **Схема:** Дозировать — доз/ирова/нн/ый — доз/ирова/нн/о.
2. **Правило**

Если глагол имеет суффикс на ОВА, то в глагольной форме (причастии или прилагательном) всегда пишется НН, поэтому НН сохраняется в наречии.

Розенталь, http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62   Пункт 6.
Отглагольные прилагательные на -ованн(ый), -ёванн(ый) пишутся с нн: балованный ребёнок, корчёванный участок.

3. **Для справок**:

Из словаря: ДОЗИРОВАТЬ; св. и нсв. что.  Это двувидовой глагол (совершенного и несовершенного вида). Поэтому от него можно образовать причастие.

Различать причастия и прилагательные в **полной форме** нет необходимости, а вот в кратком причастии (в именной части сказуемого) пишется Н, например:  Количество учебных часов в неделю строго **дозировано.**  Пользование компьютером должно быть **дозировано.**

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Кстати, в современных  художественных текстах очень много ошибок на эту тему (пишут Н вместо НН), например:

Любовь и работа должны сочетаться гармонично и **дозировано**.

Тебе просто начинают давать информацию ― строго **дозировано**, в определенной последовательности.

Конечно, эти вольности допускались ну очень **дозировано.**

Всё получается точно, **дозировано**, негрубо и зримо.

Административный ресурс ― инструмент мощный, но грубоватый, вроде топора. Его сложно применять **дозировано.**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь употребляется наречие (вопрос *как?*) от причастия, и нужны две Н:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/дозированно](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Если бы что-то было дозировано (дозирован, дозирована), то это краткая форма причастия и была бы одна Н:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Да, это причастие от *дозировать*. Поэтому *-нн-*.

С *-н-* было бы, если причастие перешло в прилагательное. Простой пример: *жарить* → *жаренный* → жареный (в оборотах, где *жаренный* остаётся причастием, пишем *-нн-*: картофель, жаренный с грибами), но — жареный картофель. Иногда грань тонка между причастием и причастием, перешедшим в прилагательные, но не в этих случаях.